# Android, Facebook SDK 3.14 share photo on wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to read image from SD-card and then post in to facebook wall. I use lastest Facebook SDK 3.14. I google about it a lot and I found a lot of code using Facebook SDK Facebook object and AsyncFacebookRunner object but they are depricated now and I dont want to use it. I try to use [WebDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/WebDialog/) from lastest SDK and it is works great except that it takes link to image already exist in WEB and I dont know how to post image from my SD-card. I google a little bit more and I read that some people do that by uploading image first to user gallery and then use WebDialog to share image uploaded to gallery. This approach not convince me because image is on wall twice. Once after upload image to gallery and second when it is share on wall. My question is: 
1) Is there any way to share image from SD-card to facebook wall?
2) If thre isnt any way to share image from SD-card to facebook wall, can I upload photo to facebook users gallery without any posting it on wall so I can share it by myself later?
3) Is there any other trick to perform this task?

Comment: You can use the FacebookDialog class. There's a PhotoShareDialogBuilder that you can use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/

Comment: Yeah, but it needs FacebookApp installed on device and I would prefer to avoid this.

Comment: True, although the likelihood of the user wanting to upload a photo to Facebook, but doesn't have the FB app installed is ... slim.

Comment: That link is now dead.